# If you withdraw principal from a Roth IRA, what happens to the amount it earned while in the account?

Tags: investing, retirement, roth-ira

I understand that you can withdraw your principal from a Roth IRA anytime without penalty. But what becomes of the earnings accumulated on that principal?

Comment: It stays in the account and can be drawn on penalty free once you've attained the specified retirement age.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After age 59 1/2, the earnings are tax free as well - with a few exceptions, such as foriegn income.  For the most part, it it safe to say that you can withdraw principal and earnings without tax liability.

Comment: For Roth it's 59 1/2 (or disabled or deceased) AND at least 5 years after you opened the Roth, or more exactly 5 years after the beginning of the year you first contributed to any Roth IRA. And I've never heard of any US tax for foreign income _in an IRA_ nor does Pub 590B have it -- although you do lose the _credit_ or _deduction_ you could have gotten if foreign income subject to foreign tax is in a normal (not tax-preferred) account.